SQL 'ORDER BY' clause slowness
SELECT pp.productID
FROM productPrices pp
LEFT JOIN products p ON pp.productID = p.productID
WHERE MATCH(p.productName) AGAINST('beef' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    AND pp.storeID IN ('store-4513')
ORDER BY pp.currentPrice LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

I have this query that runs incredibly quick without the ORDER BY but once it's added it takes >20 seconds to run. I've added a FULLTEXT index for productName, INDEX for storeID in productPrices, INDEX for currentPrice in productPrices and a few others but that doesn't help. This is what it looks like when adding EXPLAIN. The productPrices table has 1 million rows and it says it's indexing it which could be the issue.
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                              | key              | key_len | ref                       | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pp    | index  | idx_storeID,idx_storeID_productID,idx_storeID_currentPrice | idx_currentPrice | 5       | NULL                      | 78   | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_productID                                      | PRIMARY          | 52      | table.pp.productID | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+

I'm running the MariaDB server on a slow server which could be part of the reason but without the ORDER BY it runs in less than 0.2 seconds.

Without an order by, the database can walk the table and just take the first few rows that match. With an order by, the database has to examine every record in the table before it knows which to give you first. You can sometimes help this by adding an index matching the order by expression.

Would you recommend adding an index like this? CREATE INDEX idx_currentPrice_desc ON productPrices(currentPrice desc); 

more likely you have an existing index for StoreID and you need to use that for the WHERE clause. So instead, I would try adding currentPrice to the index with StoreID. So it's the same index, but two columns in that order: (StoreID, currentPrice)

Also that left-join is a code smell: the WHERE clause forces it to logically act as an inner-join. Anyway, look at it from the persepective of the server, even after adding indexes: it can either start with all the prices ordered, join the product and check the MATCH, and hope that it finds 10 rows quickly. Or it can use the fulltext index to get all the matches, loop-join all of those by ID to the price, and sort them to get top 10, hoping there aren't too many rows to join and sort. It's a difficult query whatever you do.

Usually it isn't possible to use more than one index for a given table efficiently, so you ideally have one index that helps as much as possible.
Considering just this one query, here that would be an index on (StoreID, currentPrice, productID).  StoreID to restrict it to the rows that might be looked at, currentPrice to be able to read through them in price order and stop when the limit is reached, and productID so the product table can be joined from just the index record, without having to read the main productPrices record.
But just using an index hint to tell it to use the StoreID index even though it is ordering by price may be fast enough for you that you don't need to add an additional index.
As mentioned in a comment, note that your left join says that product need not be found, but your where condition requires it, so it is effectively an inner join.  For better readability, you should change it to inner join.
